# How to use translate service in html of angular(prime ng library used)

Tags: angular, primeng-dropdowns

I am having problem in traslating items selected in ([selectedItemsLabel]="'{0} items selected'") in html in angular

{{'home.A1'| translate}}" tried this [selectedItemsLabel]="'{0} {{'home.A1'| translate}}'" but not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: items selected needs to be translated in  ([selectedItemsLabel]="'{0} items selected'")